# Google maps api marker not showing

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-maps-api-3

I can not get the marker to show up on the map. Can anyone help me find out what is wrong that would be a huge help?

Here is the code:

```
function initialize() {
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.748995, -84.387982);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, mapOptions);
    TestMarker();    
}

// Function for adding a marker to the page.
function addMarker(location) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });
}

// Testing the addMarker function
function TestMarker() {
       Atlanta = new google.maps.LatLng(33.748995, -84.387982);
       addMarker(Atlanta);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be missing the `var` keyword in front of the `marker` and `Atlanta` variables. To fix, I would also declare the `map`, `marker` and `Atlanta` variables outside of the `initialize()` function in the global space, so they are accessible to other functions.  Try this:

```
var map;
var marker;
var Atlanta;

function initialize() {
    var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.748995, -84.387982);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, mapOptions);
    TestMarker();    
}

// Function for adding a marker to the page.
function addMarker(location) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });
}

// Testing the addMarker function
function TestMarker() {
       Atlanta = new google.maps.LatLng(33.748995, -84.387982);
       addMarker(Atlanta);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Have you included the proper Google Maps js file? What does the console show?

Comment: I also updated my answer - declare `var map` outside of the `initialize()`.

Comment: I have and the console is blank

Comment: You have a few other syntax errors here I'm noticing as well. Try using exactly what I have above.

Comment: I updated it again.  You didn't declare `Atlanta` as anything either.  There were quite a few syntax issues here.

Comment: If it works please consider choosing this as the answer.  Thanks!